# Char Array Comparison using Sequential Search Algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, char, comparison

I am writing a program that grades a driving test but I am having trouble comparing the correct answers with the user input answers. On my second method keeps returning integer 1 for the "** Incorrect answers: 1" when it should be 5. I purposely made the last 5 questions incorrect to test. I am not sure what's happening here and what I am doing wrong. Great help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DriverTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int NUMBER_QUESTIONS = 20;
      char[] correct = {'A','A','A','A','A',
                        'B','B','B','B','B',
                        'C','C','C','C','C',
                        'D','D','D','D','D'};
  char[] student = new char[NUMBER_QUESTIONS + 1];
  System.out.println("Enter your answers to the exam questions.");

  for(int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_QUESTIONS; i++)
  {
     System.out.print("Question " + i + ": ");
     student[i] = kb.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
  }
  System.out.println("** Incorrect answers: " + gradeExam(correct,student));
  }

  public static int gradeExam(char[] correct, char[] student)
  {

  for (int i = 0; i < correct.length; i++)
  {
     if(correct[i] != student[i])
     {
        i++;
        return 1;
     }
  }
  return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function 'gradeExam' will terminate on the first wrong answer and return a 1, which is what the 'return' does.

You need to count the wrong answers, and then return that value. Rather:

```
int num_of_wrong_answers = 0;
if(correct[i] != student[i])
{
    num_of_wrong_answers ++;
}
return num_of_wrong_answers;
```

You need to count the number of incorrect answers, and only at the **end** of the function should **return** be called.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot however it is still giving me the incorrect number. Now it gives me 8 instead of 5.

Comment: Please note the small edit in my original answer. There should be no return inside the if.

Try hardcoding the answer into the code (like you coded 'correct') so that you don't have to type it each time. And if it still happens, show that code.

Also, if you have an IDE like Eclipse, you could put a breakpoint in the 'gradeExam' function to see exactly what happened.